# SQL get numeric rows from text column

Tags: sql, db2

How do I see if a text field is non numeric in a DB2 SQL query?

I have a text field column in a table and I only want to query rows that are 100% numbers.

Comment: title doesn't match question?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the field is 10 digits long (like mine) this would be the solution.

```
WHERE
  (  
     SUBSTRING(ID_NUM,1,1,OCTETS) BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
  OR SUBSTRING(ID_NUM,2,1,OCTETS) BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
  OR SUBSTRING(ID_NUM,3,1,OCTETS) BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
  OR SUBSTRING(ID_NUM,4,1,OCTETS) BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
  OR SUBSTRING(ID_NUM,5,1,OCTETS) BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
  OR SUBSTRING(ID_NUM,6,1,OCTETS) BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
  OR SUBSTRING(ID_NUM,7,1,OCTETS) BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
  OR SUBSTRING(ID_NUM,8,1,OCTETS) BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
  OR SUBSTRING(ID_NUM,9,1,OCTETS) BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
  OR SUBSTRING(ID_NUM,10,1,OCTETS)BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
  )
```

Comment: Surely all those `OR` between each `SUBSTRING` expression **would need to be** `AND` instead, to ensure every character position of the 10-byte character field are all decimal *digits*.? FWiW the expression in either of the following single predicates might be just as clear?; similar to what @danhi offered as 2nd example: <br> `TRANSLATE(ID_NUM,'9999999999','1234567890') = '9999999999'` or <br> `TRANSLATE(ID_NUM,'9','1234567890','9') = '9999999999'`

Answer (score 0):

I find this query works better to identify non numeric columns.

```
select  a.* from table a where (substring(testcol,1,1) 
not in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0') 
or substring(testcol,2,1) not  in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0') 
or substring(testcol ,3,1) not in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0') 
or substring(testcol,4,1) not in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0') 
or substring(testcol,5,1) not in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0') 
or substring(testcol,6,1) not in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0') 
or substring(testcol,7,1) not in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0') 
or substring(testcol ,8,1) not in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'))
```

Answer (score -1):

select myfield from mytable where isnumeric(myfield)

Comment: Does not do anything. Can't find DB2 references on `isnumeric()` either.

Comment: My mistake, I was thinking SQL Server, sorry.